# SVN: How can I move a project from one repository into another

Tags: svn, tortoise-svn

Ok, so I have these two repositories and I want to move a project from one repo to the other without losing the history. I tried using svn relocate and I got a weird message and it wouldn't let me relocate. Is there a way to do what I want?

I am using toroise svn btw

Comment: Comment by Davious: Daniel,

This case is a little more nuanced. This is going to a subdirectory in an existing repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must dump the repository, then filter the dump and reimport it into the new repository. Then you can delete the project from its original repo.

See the similar question

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337024/how-do-i-dump-one-project-out-of-a-svn-repository-which-contains-multiple-project

for more detailed explanations.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. Depending on what exactly you want to accomplish, [externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07s03.html) might be useful.